# Is forRoutes call required in Nest.js after apply middleware call?

Tags: nestjs

I would like to apply middleware to all requests.

I can write such apply as this

```
consumer
    .apply(
         session(sessionOptions)
    )
    .forRoutes("*");
```

Will this work as well?

```
consumer
    .apply(
         session(sessionOptions)
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working. `forRoutes("*")` still required.